# Set values of a column to a specific list of numbers

Tags: stata

I want to create a small test data set with some specific values:

```
x
-
1
3
4
5
7
```

I can do this the hard way:

```
. set obs 5
. generate x = .
. replace x = 1 in 1
. replace x = 3 in 2
. replace x = 4 in 3
. replace x = 5 in 4
. replace x = 7 in 5
```

I can also use the data editor, but I'd like to create a `.do` file which can recreate this data set.

So how do I set the values of a variable from a list of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a (to my mind) poorly documented feature of `input`:

```
clear
input x
    1
    3
    4
    5
    7
end
```

I say poorly documented because the title of the `input` help page is

> [D] Input -- Enter  data from keyboard

which is clearly only a subset of what this command can do.

Comment: This is often the best way whenever you can copy and paste from some source in which observations are already on separate lines. A related point is shown by `dataex` (install with `ssc install dataex`) which takes a data sample and emits the `input` code that would let someone else read the sample in. So, it defines value labels, date formats, etc. and is explicit what is string and what is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
clear 
mat x = (1,3,4,5,7) 
set obs `=colsof(x)' 
generate x = x[1, _n]
```

and another

```
clear 
mata : x = (1,3,4,5,7)'
getmata x=x
```